# How do I specify my argument will be an object

Tags: typescript

I need to tell my function that `entity` is an `object` (any object):

But if I do so :

```
export function processEntityTags(entity: object) {
    entity.label;
}
```

it says `property label doesn't exists on type object`.

This `entity` variable can have different properties so I cannot implement an `entity` `Interface`

So my question is, How can I tell my program entity will be any type of object?

Comment: you can use entity: any

Comment: Why dont you use interface? Just use duck typing on interface to use only the required properties.

Comment: Check my answer if it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface with index signature like below that has value of type `any`.

```
interface Itest{
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Then pass the Interface as the type for the parameter.This way the function will only accept an `{}` as the input parameter like below

```
export function processEntityTags(entity: Itest) {
      entity.label;
}

const t = processEntityTags({label:5}); // no error

const t = processEntityTags(6);// error
```

working demo : [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Itest%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20function%20processEntityTags(entity%3A%20Itest)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20entity.label%3B%0D%0A%20%20entity.test%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20processEntityTags(%7B%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers have gone down the route of creating an interface that could have any properties defined as anything this kind of defeats the purpose of using typescript.

You say an entity could have different properties so a single interface wont work. Each type of entity must have some shared properties to allow them to be passed into the same function so you can use [interface inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) to allow this to be typed correctly.

```
// Create a basic interface that has the label property
interface TaggableEntity{
  label: string
}

// Extend the taggable interface
interface TypeAEntity extends TaggableEntity{
  typea: string;
}

interface TypeBEntity extends TaggableEntity{
  typeb: string;
}

// Accept a Taggable Entity
function processEntityTags(entity: TaggableEntity) {
  entity.label; // Fine
  entity.typea; // Not Fine, `typea` does not exist on `TaggableEntity`
}

const typea: TypeAEntity = {
  typea: 'foo';
}

const typeb: TypeBEntity = {
  typeb: 'bar';
} 

// Although of different types both types inherit from the type accepted by the function.
processEntityTags(typea);
processEntityTags(typeb);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Create%20a%20basic%20interface%20that%20has%20the%20label%20property%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20TaggableEntity%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Extend%20the%20taggable%20interface%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20TypeAEntity%20extends%20TaggableEntity%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20typea%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20TypeBEntity%20extends%20TaggableEntity%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20typeb%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Accept%20a%20Taggable%20Entity%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20processEntityTags(entity%3A%20TaggableEntity)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20entity.label%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20entity.typea%3B%20%2F%2F%20Not%20Fine%2C%20%60typea%60%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20%60TaggableEntity%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20typea%3A%20TypeAEntity%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20typea%3A%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20typeb%3A%20TypeBEntity%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20typeb%3A%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Although%20of%20different%20types%20both%20types%20inherit%20from%20the%20type%20accepted%20by%20the%20function.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20processEntityTags(typea)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20processEntityTags(typeb)%3B)